# Create search input inside a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code that creates my dropdown, where it works:

```js
var linha = ``; 

linha += `<tr id="5">          
            <td class="text-center text-muted" style="vertical-align: middle;"><div class="tooltip-demo"><div class="most dropdown select2"><div class="caption select2-input"> <i class="pe-2x pe-va pe-7s-user"></i></div><div class="list select2-list">
      <option class="item">Option 1</option>
      <option class="item">Option 2</option>
    </div></div><div class="tooltip">Atribuir Membro</div></div></td>
          </tr>`;


$("#daberto tbody").html(linha);


$(function() {
  
  $('.dropdown > .caption').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
  });
  
  $('.dropdown > .list > .item').on('click', function() {
    $('.dropdown > .list > .item').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected').parent().parent().removeClass('open').children('.caption').text( $(this).text() );
  });
  
  $(document).on('keyup', function(evt) {
    if ( (evt.keyCode || evt.which) === 27 ) {
      $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
    }
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', function(evt) {
    if ( $(evt.target).closest(".dropdown > .caption").length === 0 ) {
      $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.tooltip-demo {
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition-property: opacity, visibility;
    transition-duration: .1s;
    position: absolute;
    top: -.75rem;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    background-color: #333;
    color: #eee;
    padding: .25rem .75rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 3.5px;
}

.most:hover ~ .tooltip,
.most:focus ~ .tooltip,
.most.active ~ .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

div.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

div.dropdown > div.caption {
  padding: 11px 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.dropdown > div.list {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

div.dropdown > div.list > option.item {
  padding: 11px 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.dropdown > div.list > option.item.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.dropdown > div.caption:hover,
div.dropdown > div.list > option.item:hover {
  color: #29a4f6;
}

div.dropdown.open > div.caption {
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

div.dropdown.open > div.list {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pixeden-stroke-7-icon@1.2.3/pe-icon-7-stroke/dist/pe-icon-7-stroke.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="align-middle mb-0 table table-borderless table-striped table-hover daberto" id="daberto">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th class="text-center col-2">Destinatário</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I wanted inside the div with the class="list", I wanted to create a search input, as shown below:

```js
var linha = ``; 

linha += `<tr id="5">
             <td class="text-center text-muted" style="vertical-align: middle;"><div class="tooltip-demo"><div class="most dropdown"><div class="caption"> <i class="pe-2x pe-va pe-7s-user"></i></div><div class="list">
      <input class="select2-search form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="search..."/>
      <div class="item">Option 1</div>
      <div class="item">Option 2</div>
    </div></div><div class="tooltip">Atribuir Membro</div></div></td>
          </tr>`;
          
$("#daberto tbody").html(linha);

$(function() {
  
  $('.dropdown > .caption').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
  });
  
  $('.dropdown > .list > .item').on('click', function() {
    $('.dropdown > .list > .item').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected').parent().parent().removeClass('open').children('.caption').text( $(this).text() );
  });
  
  $(document).on('keyup', function(evt) {
    if ( (evt.keyCode || evt.which) === 27 ) {
      $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
    }
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', function(evt) {
    if ( $(evt.target).closest(".dropdown > .caption").length === 0 ) {
      $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.tooltip-demo {
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition-property: opacity, visibility;
    transition-duration: .1s;
    position: absolute;
    top: -.75rem;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    background-color: #333;
    color: #eee;
    padding: .25rem .75rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 3.5px;
}

.most:hover ~ .tooltip,
.most:focus ~ .tooltip,
.most.active ~ .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

div.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

div.dropdown > div.caption {
  padding: 11px 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.dropdown > div.list {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

div.dropdown > div.list > div.item {
  padding: 11px 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.dropdown > div.list > div.item.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.dropdown > div.caption:hover,
div.dropdown > div.list > div.item:hover {
  color: #29a4f6;
}

div.dropdown.open > div.caption {
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

div.dropdown.open > div.list {
  display: block;
}

.select2 {
  position: relative;
}
.select2-list {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: overlay;
}
.select2-item:hover{
    background-color: #94adff31;
    cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pixeden-stroke-7-icon@1.2.3/pe-icon-7-stroke/dist/pe-icon-7-stroke.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="align-middle mb-0 table table-borderless table-striped table-hover daberto" id="daberto">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center col-2">Destinatário</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

But now I don't know how to make it look for the names inside the list that I have of options when writing in the input.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using JQuery? It's been deprecated for a while. Unless you're working on a legacy codebase I highly suggest refactoring to ES6.

In pure Javascript you need to use the filter array method. Something along the lines of:

```
const arrayOfOptionElements = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
const arrayOfOptions = [];

for (const item of arrayOfOptionElements) {
    arrayOfOptions.push(item.innerText);
}


const searchBar = document.getElementsByClassName("select2-search")[0];
searchBar.addEventListener("change", filterOptions)

const filterOptions = () => {
    const userInput = searchBar.innerText;
    const filteredOptions = arrayOfOptions.filter(option => option.includes(userInput)

    return filteredOptions
}
```

This isn't a full solution, as I'm not going to write the full thing for you, just something to get you headed in the right direction.